# Using powershell jobs to track powershell winRM remoting NO winRM timeout

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-workflow

I have got a powershell script working, the job runs a list of servers, remotely connects to the servers and runs a simple script to get the hostname from the server. The issue is that it does get stuck on some occasions. I read up on https://4sysops.com/archives/invoke-command-compensating-for-slow-responding-computers/. I came across the use of jobs where a timeout can be specified.

Here is  my complete script and at the moment, it currently hangs on some hosts.

```
workflow Connect-windows-Servers
{
param(
[string[]] 
$server_list
)


foreach -parallel -throttlelimit 50  ($server_name in $server_list){
write-output "Inside Workflow but outside inline $server_name $(Get-Date)"
    InLineScript {
    $output_status = "" | Select-Object -Property server_name, isError, result 
    $in_server_name = $using:server_name

    write-output "inline  = $in_server_name"
    $username = "my_usersname"
    $password = "my_password"
    $secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
    $password.ToCharArray() | foreach-object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
    $credentials = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,$secstr

    $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $in_server_name -ScriptBlock {   [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName() } -ErrorVariable ErrVar  -Credential $credentials
    
    write-output "Error value is $ErrVar"

    if ($ErrVar)
    {
        $output_status.server_name = $in_server_name
        $output_status.isError = $true
        $output_status.result = $ErrVar
        $deployment_output += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{server_name = $in_server_name; isError = $true ; result = $ErrVar } 


        $sql_query = "insert into my_table (servername,isfailed, result) select '$in_server_name','$true','$ErrVar'"
        write-output $sql_query

        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "db_server" -Query $sql_query -Database  "db_name"     

    }     
    else
    {

        $output_status.server_name = $in_server_name
        $output_status.isError = $false
        $output_status.result = $result
        $deployment_output += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{server_name = $in_server_name; isError = $false ; result = $result } 

        $sql_query = "insert into my_table (servername,isfailed, result) select '$in_server_name','$false','$result'"
        write-output $sql_query

        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "db_server" -Query $sql_query -Database  "db_name"       

        }
     }
  }
    }

$list = @('server1',server2)

Connect-windows-Servers -server_list $list
```

**What is the issue.**

The issue here is that the script above hangs on some hosts, and when that happens the whole process is stuck. No errors at all from winRM, this makes automation very difficult, the code also needs to be able to run in parallel as there are over 2,000 hosts.

**What have I done ?**

I introduced powershell jobs, however the issue with this is that I cant seem to be able to get the value of $results, what I want to know is hosts that were successful connection wise, get the value of the host name back and for hosts that timed out, I want to be able to identify them and most importantly use workflows or any other means to run this in parallel, please note that I am on powershell v5.

If the section below is changed to

```
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $in_server_name -ScriptBlock {   [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName() } -ErrorVariable ErrVar  -Credential $credentials
$result | wait-job timeout (1*60) | Remove-Job
```

What then happens is that I loose track of the status of the particular server as $result no longer contains the hostname and I have no way to work out which jobs timed out.

Another solution that could work using my original code snippet is if I can get winrM to gracefully timeout and if there is a way for me to know when this happens so that I can log it for the particular host.

Please ignore the hardcoded username/password, its not good practice. As I am running the script several times, its easier this way then attending to a prompt several times.

Comment: It's confusing why are you using `wait-job timeout (1*60) | Remove-Job` when you didnt specify `-AsJob` for `Invoke-Command`. Without this switch, all that jazz is being done for you

Comment: Also, `1*60 = 60`.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the code using [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-7.2) with a [`Try / Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2) and a List where you can store the possible errors.

The downside is that the loop to establish the connection is linear and it can take time.

```
$servers = 'host1', 'host2', 'host3'
$failed  = [Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$session = foreach($server in $servers) {
    try {
        New-PSSession $server -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        $failed.Add([pscustomobject]@{
            Server    = $server
            Exception = $_.ToString()
        })
    }
}

# Highly unlikely this could fail if you could establish a PSSession
if($session) {
    Invoke-Command -SessionName $session -ScriptBlock { [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName() }
    Remove-PSSession $session
}

if($failed) {
    # Has all records of failed connections with the corresponding error messages
    $failed
}
```

If you wanted something faster but dirtier you can use [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2#redirectable-output-streams):

```
$servers = 'host1', 'host2', 'host3'
$result  = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock {
    [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
} -Credential $credential -ErrorAction Continue 2>&1

$failed, $success = $result.where({ $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]}, 'Split')
$failed  # => has the possible errors
$success # => has the remote results
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found that the first solution would still time out with some hosts and the second script never completed and with no way of tracking progress, I had to kill it.